# MySQL Says Field Doesn't Exist but it Does

Tags: php, mysql

I've run into a SUPER weird error and can't seem to find out what it is. I'm running a PHP loop to query data from mySQL and it doesn't seem to work. My query looks like this

```
$q_routes = "SELECT * FROM routes";
$r_routes = mysql_query($q_routes);
while ($row_routes = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_routes)) {
    $route_id = $row_routes['route_id'];
    $route_name = $row_routes['route_short_name'];

}
```

When I echo the $route_name it shows a list of the route names. When I echo the $route_id, it has a list of blank fields.

I've gone into phpmyadmin to run a query for "SELECT route_id FROM routes and it says that route_id does not exist. When I do the same with route_name it exists. Is there any reason for this?

Table Structure[image]

Comment: What makes you so sure that it exists ?

Comment: I don't know, if that is your case, but I've run into simillar error. I can't create table, because it `sorry, table already exists`, but I can't do operations on it, because it doesn't exist....

Comment: The field does exist though. I'm looking at it. I even copy and pasted it from the column field and it's there.

When I choose from the left side in PHP my admin where it allows you to choose a field name, it's there as `route_id` (directly copied and pasted just now)

Comment: Maybe you have the same table name without this column in another database.

Comment: The table is there, and the column is there. There is nothing duplicate about it .

Comment: can you post your table structure here?

Comment: To make sure, try running the MySQL query `"show fields from routes"`.

Comment: @Boaz I run the query and it's there. Also posted the table structure

Comment: you probably have spaces or other non visible characters in the name. check the string lengths, and possibly inspect the raw bytes of the name.

Comment: A hidden character is indeed a likely suspect. Try using `mysql_fetch_row()` instead, and echo $row_routes[2], which should be `route_id`.

Comment: Please stop using mysql_* !!

Comment: Thanks all. I'm not really looking for a work around (ie. mysql_fetch_row()); I'd like to find out what the issue is and what's causing it to be an "Unknown Column".

Comment: `mysql_fetch_row()` was not suggested as a work-around. The idea is to make sure you actually get the correct value back from the query, so we can focus on the column's name as the lead suspect.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the while loop do:

```
var_dump($row_routes);
```

This will show you what fields have been fetched, along with their exact spelling and the number of characters in the strings, in case there are hidden or whitespace characters.

Comment: This is more of a comment that belongs among the suggestions above.

Comment: The questioner said: "I'd like to find out what the issue is". Doing var_dump() will show what the issue is.

Comment: I thought your answer was borderline, which is why I didn't flag it. It's a suggestion of how to possibly investigate the problem, but it doesn't inherently identify the problem. I do appreciate that you added clarification about what problems you expect this could identify.